# How to check if NodeSeq contains a particular element

Tags: xml, scala

I tried using "contains" function which is supposed to give a boolean if the nodeSeq contains an element, but its not working for me.

For example: 
seq =

```
<parent>
  <child1 />
  <child2 />
</parent>
```

If I use seq.contains("child1"), it gives me false. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeSeq seems to contain a single node (you're "parent" tag) which has children. This code seems to work:

```
nodeSeq.child.contains(<child1 />)
```

Alternatively you can use xpath to find the children

```
(nodeSeq \\ "child3").nonEmpty == false
(nodeSeq \\ "child2").nonEmpty == true
(nodeSeq \\ "parent").nonEmpty == true
```

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-xml-searching-xmlns-namespaces-xpath-parsing has some more details around the xpath support.

Comment: Thanks @AngeloGenovese. (nodeSeq \\ "child3").nonEmpty worked.

Comment: @skhaapioloir, you say this worked, but the answer has not been "accepted".  Is there something wrong?